# Lightning datatable inline edit doesn't work. the below pop-up appears on clicking save

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-datatable, updaterecord

[image: html code for datatable][image: the error pop-up]
this is the message which appears on clicking save after edit

[image: js code for handling on save]

Comment: If you want to get an answer here you need to show a part of your code in the question.
Because it is impossible to give you an answer based on your screenshot !!  Please edit the question and add your HTML and JS code.

Comment: Update - Added code as well

Comment: For future knowledge : If you share your code - share it with Copy-Pasting code, not Screenshots. So everyone could copy paste it , and try if it works.

Answer (score 0):

So it is clearly that `recordInput` variable in `saveHandleAction` method is invalid !!
As `updateRecord` require the `Id` field, which you do NOT populate !

Please see this link how to correct update record.   [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record)

However I do *NOT understand why are you using the `updateRecord` element*, as it will only **update 1 record**.
And with `lightning-datatable` inline edit you should **handle editing multiple records** !!

So I would rewrite your `saveHandleAction` method like this :

```
saveHandleAction(event){
    try {
        let updatedFields = event.detail.draftValues;

        // if you need to make some changes
        // updatedFields.forEach(element => {
        //     element['somefield'] = 'value';
        // });
        // if you need to make some changes


        updateObjects( { data: updatedFields } )
        .then( result => {

            console.log( JSON.stringify( "Apex update result: " + result ) );
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Objects updated',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
            
            refreshApex( this.aeObj ).then( () => {
                this.fldsitemValues = [];
            });        

        }).catch( error => {

            console.log( 'Error is ' + JSON.stringify( error ) );
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error updating or refreshing records',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );

        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Additional Apex class :

```
public with sharing class LwcController {

  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static String updateObjects(List<AE_Name__c> objects){
      try {
          update objects;
          return 'Success: objects updated successfully';
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
          return 'The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage();
      }
  }
}
```

**Do not forgot to import the updateObjects method in LWC :** :

```
import updateObjects from '@salesforce/apex/LwcController.updateObjects';
```

Comment: Using the update I get -  MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call. How to supply an id for the records we're editing ?

Comment: @ShreyashAnarase in <Lighting-datatable> you added " key-field=AE_Name__c" ". You should change it to the Id field. Make sure that you retrieve the Id field when you query your data in Apex.

Comment: That worked thanks.

Comment: @ShreyashAnarase you are welcome. Please mark this answer as the one that solved your problem. Thanks